# how to find telephonic API to check whether the called party phone was switched off or not

Tags: java, android, telephony

In android is there any class in telephonic API  to check  whether the called party phone was switched off or not ..

Answer (score 0):

check out twilio.com it is telephonic API from which you can call and receive phone calls and text messages, it is basically Skype but taken apart to components that you can use separately in your app.